# The jCenter & Bintray is Shutting Down. Now What? How to resolve that If third party library used?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, bintray, jcenter

The jCenter & Bintray is Shutting Down.
So how we can resolve this and what will do if third party libraries are used in project.?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In all of your `build.gradle` files replace `jcenter()` by `mavenCentral()` (or just remove it if mavenCentral is already set).

If you still have a dependency that need `jcenter()` (with this type of error: `Could not find com.jeroenmols:mylibrary:1.0.0.`) you can restrict the usage of jCenter to only this dependency:

```
jcenter() {
    content {
        includeModule("com.jeroenmols", "mylibrary")
    }
}
```

JCenter will allow to download dependencies until [February 1, 2022](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration), so until then you can contact the developers of the missing library and ask them to migrate away from jCenter.

[Source and more details](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2021/02/04/migratingjcenter/)

**EDIT:**
JFrog updated his [announce](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) that they will keep jcenter as a read-only repository indefinitely. So you should be able to keep it as a reliable source for artifact if you still have dependencies from jCenter.