# Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom

Tags: android, react-native

Could not GET

> 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.

Received status code `502` from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle `'offline mode'` and sync project

Facing in react native application. `@react-native-community/`

Please update if you have any solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The jCenter & Bintray is Shutting Down. Now What? How to resolve that If third party library used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064056/the-jcenter-bintray-is-shutting-down-now-what-how-to-resolve-that-if-third-p)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/67064056/7373144